# Multiple conditional RewriteRules htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, retina

I'm using [Adaptive-Images](http://adaptive-images.com) on a WordPress Theme and I'd like to redirect some normal ratio images to double ratio/size images for HiDPI/Retina support, too. But the `RewriteRule` from Adaptive-Images will override the HiDPI `RewriteRule`.

Both Scripts works alone well, but not together.
Can I exclude some image sizes from the main `RewriteRule` by Adaptive-Images? Or any other solution?

Thanks
Ogni

#### My `.htaccess` looks like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Adaptive-Images
# http://adaptive-images.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} cms/assets
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ cms/wp-content/themes/roots/inc/adaptive-images.php

# HiDPI
# http://cup.wpcoder.de/wordpress-hidpi-bilder/ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} HTTP_IS_HIDPI
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1-554x380.$2 -f
RewriteRule ^(cms/assets.+)-277x190\.(jpe?g|png)$ $1-554x380.$2 [L] 

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried swapping the order of the two rules and adding a `[L]` flag to the adaptive images rule?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# prevent any looping
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# HiDPI
# http://cup.wpcoder.de/wordpress-hidpi-bilder/ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} HTTP_IS_HIDPI
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1-554x380.$2 -f
RewriteRule ^(cms/assets.+)-277x190\.(jpe?g|png)$ $1-554x380.$2 [L] 

# Adaptive-Images
# http://adaptive-images.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} cms/assets
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ cms/wp-content/themes/roots/inc/adaptive-images.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

It seems like if the request is specifically for `277x190` sized images, the HiDPI rules will therefore match first. Otherwise, the Adaptive rule will match.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your script works perfectly for me. Swapping order and adding a [L] flag to the adaptive images rule doesn´t work for me.